# How to develop simple application to read NCF tags using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, tags, nfc

I'm new to NFC, I've read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc, but it's really confusing for me, because the examples are quite messy for beginners.

What I need to understand:
1. What function/syntax to read (yes, just READ) from NFC tag?
2. Where should I put that function/syntax? (android manifest/ .java?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Android will read automatically the content of tags formatted according to the [NFC Forum standards](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/#tagtypes). The data read from such a tag, in the form of an [NDEF message](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/#ndefts), will be delivered to your app in an [NDEF_DISCOVERED Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#ndef-disc). So for such a tag there is no real need for your app to communicate with the tag directly itself.

If you want to communicate with a tag that does not follow the NFC Forum standards, than it depends somewhat on the actual tag how to do this. A couple of examples, for commonly used tag types, can be found at http://nearfieldcommunication.com/developers/android/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) for creating NDEF messages. I suggest you [start](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/wiki/GettingStartedAndroid) with an NDEF message with an Android Application Record and a Text Record.